# Loop detection in javascript's built-in functions

Tags: javascript

I obtained the following trace from Chrome developer tool's console:

```
> a = [1]
[1]
> b = [2, a]
[2, Array[1]]
> a.push(b)
2
> a.toString()
"1,2,"
```

It seems the `toString()` intelligently skipped the recursive part of the object graph. Is this a standard behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `a.toString()` does not have anything to do with browser consoles. He could have as well done `alert(a.toString());`

Comment: Would have been cool if it had logged "1,2,nice try"

Comment: Chrome shows `[1, Array[2]]` and expands virtually infinitely http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sXURS/

Comment: In nodejs I see `[ 1, [ 2, [Circular] ] ]`

Comment: node prints `[ 1, [ 2, [Circular] ] ]`.

Comment: @TedHopp: Did you actually call `.toString()`, or did you just use the default representation that the REPL gives? It appears as though the REPL uses the `.valueOf()` representation instead of the `.toString()`.

Comment: @j08691: You're not logging the `toString()` value. Chrome uses the `.valueOf()` representation of `a` by default, which apparently also catches the circular reference but gives a different display. Firefox's default Web Console catches it for the `toString()` but not the `valueOf()`, so if you do `console.log(a)`, it'll give you a Too Much Recursion error.

Comment: @IHateLazy - You're right. When I explicitly call `toString()`, it prints `'1,2,'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `[ECMA-262: 15.4.4.2]:` `Array.prototype.toString ( )`
>
> When the `toString` method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let `array` be the result of calling `ToObject` on the `this` value.
> 2. Let `func` be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of `array` with argument `"join"`.
> 3. If `IsCallable(func)` is `false`, then let `func` be the standard built-in method `Object.prototype.toString` (15.2.4.2).
> 4. Return the result of calling the `[[Call]]` internal method of `func` providing `array` as the `this` value and an empty arguments list.
>
> **NOTE** The `toString` function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its `this` value be an `Array` object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the `toString` function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent.

All of this basically means that the result is a call to `Array.prototype.join()`, which is defined in `15.4.4.5` and doesn't mandate any recursion detection:

> `[ECMA-262: 15.4.4.5]:` `Array.prototype.join (separator)`
>
> The elements of the array are converted to `String`s, and these `String`s are then concatenated, separated by occurrences of the separator. If no separator is provided, a single comma is used as the separator.
>
> The join method takes one argument, `separator`, and performs the following steps:
>
> 1. Let `O` be the result of calling `ToObject` passing the `this` value as the argument.
> 2. Let `lenVal` be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of `O` with argument `"length"`.
> 3. Let `len` be `ToUint32(lenVal).`
> 4. If `separator` is `undefined`, let `separator` be the single-character `String` `","`.
> 5. Let `sep` be `ToString(separator)`.
> 6. If `len` is `zero`, return the empty `String`.
> 7. Let `element0` be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of `O` with argument `"0"`.
> 8. If `element0` is `undefined` or `null`, let `R` be the empty `String`; otherwise, Let `R` be `ToString(element0)`.
> 9. Let `k` be 1.
> 10. Repeat, while `k` < `len`
>
>     1. Let `S` be the `String` value produced by concatenating `R` and `sep`.
>     2. Let `element` be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of `O` with argument `ToString(k)`.
>     3. If `element` is `undefined` or `null`, Let `next` be the empty `String`; otherwise, let `next` be `ToString(element)`.
>     4. Let `R` be a `String` value produced by concatenating `S` and `next`.
>     5. Increase `k` by 1.
> 11. Return `R`.
>
> The `length` property of the `join` method is 1.
>
> **NOTE** The `join` function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its `this` value be an `Array` object. Therefore, it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the `join` function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent.

So, is it a standard-guaranteed behaviour? **No.**